# How to get UserName from java.sql.Connection - SQL Server DB?

Tags: java, sql-server

I am using Weblogic along with Microsoft SQL Server, and I want to get the username of the connection using Java code. The code is returning "dbo"  instead of "sa" that is the login name.

When I enter the below code:

```
 InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
 DataSource ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup(jndiName);
 Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
 connection.setAutoCommit(false);
 System.out.println(conn.getMetaData().getUserName());
```

I tried two alternatives:
First I tried the query :

```
SELECT a.name AS Login
FROM sys.server_principals AS a
  JOIN sys.database_principals as U
     ON a.SID = U.SID
     WHERE u.name = 'dbo';
```

which correctly returned "sa" but unfortunately I cannot use this query in my code as the user that I need does not have admin rights and I cannot access these tables.

The second solution that I tried is the following code:

```
Method getter = new PropertyDescriptor("user", ds.getClass()).getReadMethod();      
String value = (String)getter.invoke(ds);
```

But this did not work for me either, as I got the following exception :

```
 java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: isUser
        at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.<init>(PropertyDescriptor.java:106)
        at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.<init>(PropertyDescriptor.java:70)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.rulegenerators.adpPBCASHIERCREATEDBY.CREATEDBY(adpPBCASHIERCREATEDBY.java:105)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.rulegenerators.adpPBCASHIERCREATEDBY.implementation(adpPBCASHIERCREATEDBY.java:52)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.rulegenerators.tcBaseRuleGenerator.run(tcBaseRuleGenerator.java:176)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.rulegenerators.tcAdapterExecuter.executeRuleGenerators(tcAdapterExecuter.java:266)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.util.tcPrePopulateUtility.setDataFromAdapter(tcPrePopulateUtility.java:1094)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.util.tcPrePopulateUtility.prePopulate(tcPrePopulateUtility.java:389)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.util.tcOrderPackages.computeProcessFormData(tcOrderPackages.java:865)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.util.tcOrderPackages.createOrder(tcOrderPackages.java:428)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.util.tcOrderPackages.orderPackageForUser(tcOrderPackages.java:180)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcOIU.provision(tcOIU.java:869)
        at com.thortech.xl.dataobj.tcOIU.eventPostInsert(tcOIU.java:364)
```

Has anyone managed to find a solution to this?  How can the user login be retrieved through the Datasource?

Thanks

Comment: I would like to retrieve this information through Java code. This information is stored int he Datasource , I think someone should be able to retrieve it somehow

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `CURRENT_USER`?

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER;
```

See [CURRENT_USER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql) for details.

Comment: Hello , I tried this query and it returns "dbo" and not "sa".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this is what you want
SELECT [ORIGINAL_LOGIN()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/original-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The user that I am connecting has not access to this function.

Comment: I would rather prefer a solution to get the user through java code and through the datasource or the connection